# I try to find the last two digits of $2019^{102^{830}}$ in basis 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I me preparing an exam with an old exam question we received, and Im trying to find the last two digits of $2019^{102^{830}}$ in basis 7.

So here is what I ve got so far:

The last two digits are of the form $$a_{1}7+a_{0}$$ with $a\in \{1,…,6\}$ which can be maximally $6\bullet7+6= 48$
$$\implies x\equiv2019^{102^{830}} mod 49$$
Using now Euler makes it: $$x\equiv2019^{102^{830}mod\varphi(49)}mod49\equiv2019^{102^{830}mod42}mod49$$

Now since $gcd(830,42)\neq 1$ I split it up into $$y\equiv 102^{830}mod7 $$and$$y\equiv 102^{830}mod6$$ (here I m not sure anymore if I may do this)
Then I apply Euler again: $$y\equiv 102^{830 mod\varphi(7)}\equiv 102^{830 mod6}\equiv 102^2$$
Then is $$x\equiv 2019^{102^2mod42}mod49\equiv 2019^{30}mod49$$
And this is the maximum I find it to be reducible, but it is still too big.
Any help or correction would be very much appreciated . Thank you in advance :)

Comment: This is hard to read.  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on formatting for this site.

Comment: @lulu thank your for your link, I ll do this now

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/modular-exponentiation-by-hand-ab-bmod-c

Comment: Use Carmichael's function, the problem will left very easy using this.


 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

Comment: First  replace 830 by 830 mod φ(42), i.e. 2. Then $102^2$ by $102^2\bmod{42},$ i.e. 30. Then $2019^{30}$ by $(2019\bmod{49})^{30}\bmod{49}=32^3\bmod49=36.$ But I think this post might be considered as a duplicate of the related one pointed above by @Arthur

Comment: Thanks very much for these great answers and the link